# command shuffle not worked in android studio

Tags: android, algorithm, fisher-yates-shuffle

I am a beginner in java programming language

I tried to implement Fisher Yates's algorithm in my code, but when I run the application it doesn't randomize my puzzle. when I was looking for references I was confused about the correct location to place the command so I could randomize the puzzle.

previously I used collection.shuffle , but I was told to use fisher yates manual.

```
    static void shuffleArray(int[] pieces)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = pieces.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Swap
            int a = pieces[index];
            pieces[index] = pieces[i];
            pieces[i] = a;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);
        setName();

        //Button to go to the StartActivity
        goHome = findViewById(R.id.goHome);
        goHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goHome();
            }
        });

        //timer-------------------------------------------------------
        //counter initializing
        countTimer = findViewById(R.id.count_timer);
        countTimer.setText("OSecs");
        timer.start();//starting timer
        //-------------------------------------------------timer


        RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String assetName = intent.getStringExtra("assetName");
        //picture from camera and gallery ------------------------------------------------
        mCurrentPhotoPath = intent.getStringExtra("mCurrentPhotoPath");
        mCurrentPhotoUri = intent.getStringExtra("mCurrentPhotoUri");
        //-------------------------------------------------picture from camera

        // run image related code after the view was laid out
        // to have all dimensions calculated
        imageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (assetName != null) {
                    setPicFromAsset(assetName, imageView);
                } else if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) { //added else if picture from camera
                    setPicFromPath(mCurrentPhotoPath, imageView);
                } else if (mCurrentPhotoUri != null) {
                    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoUri));
                }
                pieces = splitImage();
                TouchListener touchListener = new TouchListener(PuzzleActivity.this);

                // shuffle pieces order
                //Collections.shuffle(pieces);

                // --- SWITCH FOR COMPLEXITY LEVELS ---
                // positioning and size of pieces-------------------------------------------
                int border = 28; //boarder size from xml
                double ratio = (double) ((layout.getBottom() - imageView.getBottom()) - 2 * border) / imageView.getHeight();
                if (ratio > 1) {
                    ratio = 1;
                }
                positioningOfPuzzlePieces(touchListener, border, getRows(), getCols(), ratio, layout, imageView);
            }
        });
    }
```

[code](https://pastebin.com/5Mj6US3K)